# Strain As A Function of Deflection of a Hollow Cylinder

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanical, strength, springs, elastic-modulus

I should think that there would be a direct correlation of strain to deflection of a hollow thin-walled cylinder, but I've seen nothing as of yet. I must be missing something. For example, let's say I had a 2.75" diameter steel tube with a .01" wall thickness and I press into it with a deflection of .135". What would be the strain of this motion?

Answer (score 1):

Since "$strain = \dfrac{\text{change in length}}{\text{original length}} = \dfrac{\Delta L}{L}$

Yes, you have missed the length ($L$), whether it is the beam length (the usual case), or the perimeter of the tube (a more complicated matter).

Comment: +1. Precisely. Stress is proportional to strain (a percentage), not deflection (a distance).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean radial deflection, then the tangential strain would simply be radial deflection divided by the radius:
$$\epsilon_t = 2\times \frac{.135}{2.75}$$